# JavaScript normal function vs arrow function - how to set new scope

Tags: javascript, data-binding, this, bind

```
const obj1 = {
  test: function() {
    console.log(this);
  }
};

const obj2 = {
  test: () => {
    console.log(this);
  }
};

obj1.test();
obj2.test();
```

I need a new scope in my method, but after running something in the callback, I want to bind the scope back to the global object, like in `obj2`.

Something like:

```
const obj1 = {
  test: function() {
    const newvalue = this.y;
    scope = bind(scope)
    this.globaldata = newvalue
  }
};
```

I hope it is clear what I mean, I have to access both scopes in a callback, acutally the `data` object in a vue instance. Is something like that possible?

Comment: Why not `const obj = { test(){ console.log(this); } };`? See [method notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
const obj1 = {
  self: this,
  test: function() {
    const contextOfObj1 = this;
    const contextOfVueComponentInstance = obj1.self
    obj1.self.globaldata = newvalue
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

simple function for normal usage
arrow function for OOP usage

the better way by making constructor and then make objects from this constructor

for ex :

```
// constructor 
function obj(){
    // arrow function 'recommended'
    this.test1 = () =>{
        console.log(this);
    }
   // normal function
    this.test2 = function(){
        console.log(this);
    }
}
   

// new object from constructor
const obj1 = new obj();
const obj2 = new obj();

obj1.test1();
obj1.test2();

obj2.test1();
obj2.test2();
```

Comment: thank you for your effort, but it actually has nothing to do with my problem :/

Comment: the best way for control multiple objects by 'contractor parent' :)